# Chrome not sending POST requests on localhost, Firefox works fine

Tags: firefox, forms, google-chrome

I have copied the simple [Django forms example](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) exactly, running on localhost. The basic contact form example should submit a POST request when you click the Submit button.

I'm running Chrome on Mac Snow Leopard, and whenever I submit the form, the page simply reloads with an empty form: I can see from the runserver output that it's not sending a POST - instead it's sending a GET request.

If I open the same page in Firefox on Mac Snow Leopard, and submit the form, I can see it's sending a POST request (as it should be).

Looking at the source in Chrome, the form definitely says `method="post"`.

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post"> 
<p><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label> <input id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" /></p> 
<p><label for="id_message">Message:</label> <input type="text" name="message" id="id_message" /></p> 
<p><label for="id_sender">Sender:</label> <input type="text" name="sender" id="id_sender" /></p> 
<p><label for="id_cc_myself">Cc myself:</label> <input type="checkbox" name="cc_myself" id="id_cc_myself" /></p> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

External sites with POST forms seem to work OK in Chrome.

In addition, if I fill the form in incorrectly, in Chrome the page just reloads, with a GET request, as before; in Firefox the form gets validated, as it should.

I've tried with other POST forms on localhost and got the same result.

I know Chrome for Mac has its quirks, but what on earth is going on?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely being caused by Chrome treating each file:// URL as a [different domain](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html).  Try launching Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` option and see if that helps.

**Update**: You'll have to close all existing Chrome instances and launch a fresh instance with that option to notice any difference.

Comment: Thanks. Could be, although: (i) I have the problem on forms that don't involve file uploads, and (ii) forms have always previously worked fine on locahost in Chrome, this seems to be a new thing. I'm just trying to work out how to launch Chrome from the command line in Mac OS...... sigh

Comment: My comment had nothing to do with file uploads.  If you're accessing the web page from a `file://` URI instead of via an `http://` URI, then every file is considered its own domain.  The reason you wouldn't have seen this before is that this behavior was only enabled on Feb. 24th's dev channel update.

Comment: Oh I see. No, I was using http://localhost:8080. The behaviour has gone away now. Bizarre! Thanks anyway.